# How to use subdomains and folders in Nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I would like to use subdomain and folder in Nginx like so:

```
myexample.example.com/admin
```

So basically all traffic directed to this address will be directed to a static html file. I've tried the following without success:

```
server {

 index index.html index.htm;
 server_name myexample.example.com;

location /admin{
  root /home/user/apps/myapp/current/dist;
}


}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
server {
 root /usr/share/nginx/www;
 index index.html index.htm;
 server_name myexample.example.com;
 error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;
 access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

location /admin{
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html /usr/share/nginx/www/admin.html =404;
  #Make sure this file exists by doing 'cat /usr/share/nginx/www/admin.html'
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I'm getting a 404. Curiously, in the `nginx.access.log` does show an entry, but no entry in the `ngingx.error.log`

Comment: First: By default error log is set to debug level. You may want to set it to info level. Like this: error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log info;  Second: Sorry my answer had a typo. "root" word should not be there. I have corrected the try_files directive. Please try that now. Also please make sure that /usr/share/nginx/www/admin.html actually exists and is accessible and has some reasonable html inside.

Comment: Where should I set the debug level? In the `nginx.conf` at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`? If yes, do I need to create a new directive? (I'm asking because I've seem this info on the web, but when I added directly to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and used `configtest` it came back with an error.

Comment: There has been an improvement. Now if I try `example.myexample.com` it works, but not `example.myexample.com/admin` which still gives me an 404. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Try the refined snippet above. I have added location directive for /. Try to have different physical html files for both the urls for easily distinguishing which one is getting served. And you may want to supply the logs for further help. Thanks.

Comment: How can I enable the logs? In the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`? If yes, as a new directive? The above didn't work either... Now both doesn't work (`example.myexample.com` nor `example.myexample.com/admin`)

Comment: The logs should be enabled by default. Go to /var/log/nginx and do "ls -lrt". The latest modified logs would end up in the last and you can inspect them. You can remove the "location /" directive. Its unnecessary. You can put the err_log directive at various levels. Here, it make sense to put it inside the server block. Further refining the answer. More documentation can be found here. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97859/discussion-between-ashish-anand-and-wagnermatosuk).